# InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex using ShowDialog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration, showdialog

I have a VB6 Project that I have converted over to .NET using Visual Studio 2008. I have some code that uses ShowDialog. The code worked just fine in VB6. In VS 2008 the code doesn't throw an error during a build or compile. I just get an error at run time, this is error:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex

This is the code that the error is thrown on:

```
frmAddMethod.ShowDialog()
```

The call stack:

> > prjDrawSafe.exe!prjDrawSafe.frmMain.cmdAddDrawing_Click(Object eventSender = {Text = "Add Drawing"}, System.EventArgs eventArgs = {X = 59 Y = 8 Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left}) Line 60   Basic

Can someone please tell me how to fix this error so that the code will work in .NET/?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  If so, could you please post the details from that as well?  Also, a call stack would be helpful.

Comment: The error is in the form itself and is just being exposeud through `ShowDialog`.  Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @StevenDoggart call stack was updated in my question.

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete call stack.  Or, at least, if it is, the interesting call stack must be on an inner exception.  How about this... Can you call the `ToString` method on the exception object and post the entire thing?  That would show the full call stack and all of the inner exceptions.

Comment: I think that your code is somehow invoking the `cmdAddDrawing_Click` event where the error is happening.

Answer (score 4):

One of the controls on your converted form has a SelectedIndex property set to 0 that is not supported in .NET. There are a couple of ways to sort this out:

Search the 'generated form designer code' (or whatever name it is) region for a SelectedIndex property of a control and fix the one(s) that are zero.

Manually select each control in the form designer and check the Selectedindex property, change any that are zero.